# Combine two or multiple classes with MultiLabelBinarizer

Tags: deep-learning

Is it possible to combine two classes to get a single entry for the labels with MultiLabelBinarizer?
Normally one gets

```
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

x = ['a', 'c', 'd']
y = ['a', 'b', 'e']
z = ['c', 'd', 'e']

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=labels)
a = mlb.fit_transform([x, y, z])

print(a)
```

```
[[1 0 1 1 0]
 [1 1 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1]]
```

But what I want is to combine two classes e.g if 'a' or 'b' is present, the label for x should look like

```
[[1 1 1]]
```

So for 'a'+'b', 'c', 'd'+'e' the above should look like

```
[[1 1 1]
 [1 0 1]
 [0 1 1]]
```

I just want to know if it is possible. Implementing some functions to get the same result is also possible, but I have a lot of classes and I want to speed things up.